# Black hole sending in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

In the past I have used the @bh.exacttarget.com domain for testing. My understanding is OMM drops these domains and doesn't actually send.

1. Is this an acceptable/viable testing approach for new end to end processes?
2. Is there an foreseen or advisable issues with this?
3. Does the black hole address still count as a send?
4. Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to answer your questions:

1. Yes, this is perfectly suitable for testing.
2. There are no foreseen issues that I am aware of; this does not affect your sender reputation.
3. Yes, this would still count as a **send** if you are deploying an email, however, if you are using a blackhole email address in Reply Mail Management as a Routing Address for remaining replies, then it won't count (when an email is sent by RMM).
4. I'm not aware of any public documentation.

FYI, we typically use the @bh.exacttarget.com email domain (for the uninitiated, you can send an email to `InsertAnythingHere`@bh.exacttarget.com) for the following use cases:

1. Routing remaining RMM replies
2. Execute AMPscript in an email to 'do stuff', then include an email Activity in an Automation, but send to a list with one Subscriber (a @bh.exacttarget.com email).